# Propagate UPDATE to dynamically determined table

Tags: postgresql, database-design, triggers

In PostgreSQL I have created trigger procedure to do some validate and to execute some queries before inserting or updating rows in table.For insert operation my trigger works well so I'm executing some queries but for update I'm not able to execute queries.

```
CREATE FUNCTION RECORDS_VALIDATE() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
DECLARE
 tblVar text := dynamically im creating table name;
BEGIN
IF NEW.date <= CURRENT_DATE THEN
 RAISE NOTICE 'DATE IS LESS THAN THE CURRENT DATE'; 
 RETURN NULL;   
END IF;

IF (TG_OP = 'UPDATE') THEN
  EXECUTE 'UPDATE '|| tblVar || ' SET id = $1,date = $2 where id = $3'
  USING NEW.id,NEW.date,OLD.id;
 RETURN NULL;
END IF;
IF(TG_OP = 'INSERT') THEN 
  EXECUTE 'INSERT INTO ' || tblVar || ' VALUES($1,$2)' 
  USING NEW.id, NEW.date;
  RETURN NULL;
END IF;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Trigger

```
CREATE TRIGGER RECORDS BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON RECORDS
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE RECORDS_VALIDATE();
```

NOTE:
   RECORDS is my base table from this base table name I'm creating table dynamically so I don't want to insert the rows in RECORDS thats why I'm returning NULL I need to insert rows in newly created table so using execution command I'm running the query to insert rows in newly created table.

INSERT
 This will insert rows in newly created table not in RECORDS

```
INSERT INTO BILLING_RECORDS VALUES(1,date '2013-10-15');
```

UPDATE
 While running this rows not updated in the newly created table.not giving error also. I'm getting output as UPDATE 0

```
UPDATE RECORDS SET id = 10,date = date '2013-12-30' where id=1;
```

Comment: Did you created two different triggers for INSERT and UPDATE events or did you used OR in trigger declaration? e.g. `create trigger trg_test_table_2 AFTER insert or update on test_table_2 FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE RECORDS_VALIDATE();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you're building up partitioning autmation triggers here. I've been working on exactly the same issue recently.

1. Use only `ON INSERT` trigger for your *base* table (I suppose `records` it is).

   This trigger will be moving records into the *desired* partitions.
2. For the `ON UPDATE` part, adding trigger to your *base* table has no meaning, as it is empty by your design. Instead, you should create such a trigger for each *partition* that you're using, and if you're creating them dynamically, then you should make sure each such partition has it's own trigger. Still, they all can share a single function.

One more thing to remember.
When you're updating a column that is your partitiong key, you have to be extra careful:

- if you've used `CHECK` constraint to restrict key range within your partition, you will get exceptions;
- if no checking is done, you might end up with a messy data layout.

So instead of `UPDATE` of the partitioning key column *and* in case new value corresponds to a different partition, you should do `DELETE` + `INSERT` instead.

Another approach is to completely restrict changes to the partitiong key column(s). You can do it:

- in the trigger, comparing `OLD` and `NEW` values;
- granting `UPDATE` privilege only for those columns that are not part of your partitioning key.

Answer (score 0):

It's a before trigger and you're returning null -- this cancels the statement. Return new instead.

Or more appropriately, since it has side effects, make it an after trigger.

Extra note: use quote_ident() on tblVar, or cast it to regclass, so it's sanitized.

---

> UPDATE While running this rows not updated in the newly created table.not giving error also.i'm getting output as UPDATE 0

This is because you cancel the update. The 0 corresponds to the number of affected rows, and holds what was returned by the very last query -- which you cancel. This is one of the reasons you should never have side effects in a before trigger.

Consider looking into using an updatable view instead of a table, and using `instead of` triggers to process inserts and updates as needed.

Comment: RECORDS is my base table from this base table name i'm creating table dynamically so i dont want to insert the rows in RECORDS thats why i'm returning NULL i need to insert rows in newly created table so using execution command i'm running the query to insert rows in newly created table.

Comment: I'd suggest editing your question to make it more clear how it's not working, then.

Answer (score 0):

When you returns `NULL` from trigger for INSERT operation no records are added in table `RECORDS`.

When you update table `RECORDS` and no records affected your trigger will not execute. Change you return statement to `NEW`

```
  EXECUTE 'INSERT INTO ' || tblVar || ' VALUES($1,$2)' 
  USING NEW.id, NEW.date;
  RETURN NEW;
```

and for `UPDATE`

```
  EXECUTE 'UPDATE '|| tblVar || ' SET id = $1,date = $2 where id = $3'
  USING NEW.id,NEW.date,OLD.id;
  RETURN NEW;
```

Comment: yes i know..y i'm returning NULL means i'm inserting rows in tblVar(newly created table) not in RECORDS.

Comment: You have to look RULEs in PostgreSQL. http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-createrule.html . I am not sure that you can solve you task using triggers. But on my opinion functions will be better match.

Answer (score 0):

`RETURN NULL` cancels the INSERT / UPDATE on the current row for BEFORE triggers, but it does **not** cancel the side effects. Other answers are incorrect in this regard.

The test case above should *work*. I tested it Postgres 9.1. **However** ...

Your **INSERT** statement is bound to fail, because you are inserting into another table:

```
INSERT INTO BILLING_RECORDS records VALUES(1,date '2013-10-15');
```

Your **UPDATE** statement probably fails, because there is no matching row in `records`, since the row was inserted in `<dynamically im creating table name;>` and is not visible in `records`.

```
UPDATE RECORDS SET id = 10,date = date '2013-12-30' where id=1;
```

You could use an [**updatable VIEW**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/rules-views.html#RULES-VIEWS-UPDATE) ([like @Denis already proposed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19316122/939860)) with an INSTEAD trigger. Then the rows of secondary tables would be visible in the view. But that's not possible with fully dynamic table names. You would have to *know* involved table names at creation time.

What could work here is [**inheritance**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/ddl-inherit.html). This cascades `UPDATE` to inheriting tables automatically. But not `INSERT`, and a number of limitations apply. Like, foreign key constraints on the master table do not work, etc.

The `UPDATE` could also work with a [**`RULE`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/rules.html). Then the `WHERE` clause can be propagated before the operation is canceled. Again, not possible with dynamic table names. You might be able to do some magic with `NOTIFY` ...

What you are trying to do is hard to achieve. I would probably pack the whole logic into a plpgsql function and call it instead of trying to use plain `INSERT` and `UPDATE` statements.